# Why vue.js not set data?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using, Vue.js, with web pack. Vue not set this.title, only render "Title" and items. When show "this.title" on console.log, this print "undefined"

I have this code.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <li v-for="i in items">
            {{ i.name }}
        </li>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => {
          return {
            title: "Title",
            items: [
                {name: "item 1"},
                {name: "item 2"},
                {name: "item 3"},
                {name: "item 4"}                ]
          }
        },
        created: () => {
            console.log(this.artists)
            this.title = "New title"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using arrow function to define a lifecycle method.

> All lifecycle hooks automatically have their this context bound to the instance, so that you can access data, computed properties, and methods. **This means you should not use an arrow function to define a lifecycle method** (e.g. created: () => this.fetchTodos()). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and this.fetchTodos will be undefined.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: "Title"
    },
    // NOT WORK
    /*
    created: () => {
        console.log(this)
        this.title = "New title"
    }
    */
    // WORKS
    created() {
        console.log(this)
        this.title = "New title"
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/cLs4d5cp/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is because `() =>` assigns `this` to the parent `this` of the scope.

Since the parent of your script has no `this` defined it will be undefined in your function.

Answer (score 0):

The vue proxy your variables to vue instace. Example methods, data, computed, and when you use ()=>(Arrow syntax) your this is not equals with vue instance.
You should use simple function. This is a little magic what vue doing in the background for you.